# Why doesn't the RxJS 5 reference documentation describe a catch operator?

Tags: rxjs5

Several tutorials on RxJS 5 talk about a `catch` operator but I can't see any info in the [reference documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html). Why not? Is it supported?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit further down in the documentation: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-catch

```
Rx.Observable.throw(new Error('pow'))
  .catch(err => Rx.Observable.of('caught: ' + err.message))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```